# Streamgraph D3 v2 to D3 v4 stack issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to migrate streamgraph example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136) from D3 v2 to D3 v4

I didn't know how to migrate the stack code to v4 I looked into the documentation but couldn't find equivalent scaling function to d3.stack.

D3.v2:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height-10, 0]);
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
.offset("silhouette")
.values(function(d) { return d.values; })
.x(function(d) { return d.date; })
.y(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

D3.v4:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([height-10, 0]);    

var stack = d3.stack()
.offset(d3.stackOffsetSilhouette)
.keys(function(d) { return d.values; })
//.x(function(d) { return d.date; })
//.y(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Here is a fiddle link to the code https://jsfiddle.net/vcbm1gmv/

Thanks

Comment: No one can answer this question without knowing what your data looks like...

Comment: @user2628404 - Were you able to find the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing without success. You should try this instead:  https://github.com/curran/d3-area-label (I found the link on the [original author of the streamgraph's website](http://leebyron.com/streamgraph/))